# Mostrar titulo siempre visible

Tags: android

Estoy programando en android y necesito que mis marcadores siempre estén visibles en el título.

Este es el código que utilizo:

```
if ((latN != 0)&& lonN != 0){

    Marker marcador1 = mGoogleMap
                       .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                       .position(new LatLng(latN, lonN))
                       .title(dato.substring(0, dato.indexOf("$")))
                       .snippet("que es esto") 
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.negocio2)));


    marcador1.showInfoWindow();
}
```

Este código funciona muy bien pero sólo me muestra la información del último marcador.

Answer (score 0):

Resolví el problema, tenia que dibujar iconos que se parecieran a los marcadores este es el código que utilice:

```
package com.example.framac.app_framac;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.RedirectException;

public class MostrarMapa extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_mapa);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
/*
        Marker marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(-16.526988,-68.266685))
                        .title("MARITSA CONDORI")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(setMarkerDrawable("142")))
                .snippet("FRENTE CASA AZUL")
        );

         mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(-16.559788,-68.916685))
                        .title("RUTH APAZA")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(setMarkerDrawable("36598")))
                 .snippet("GARAJE ROJO RNO 980")

        );

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(-16.526788,-68.216685))
                        .title("ROXANA CORO")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(setMarkerDrawable("3605")))
                .snippet("PARED TIGO NRO 134")
        );
*/


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String dato = extras.getString("PLIST");
        ObtDatos(dato);



    }

    public Bitmap setMarkerDrawable(String dato) {
        int background = R.drawable.marcadorcasa;

/* DO SOMETHING TO THE ICON BACKGROUND HERE IF NECESSARY */
/* (e.g. change its tint color if the number is over a certain threshold) */

        Bitmap icon = drawTextToBitmap(background, String.valueOf(dato));

        return icon;
    }

    public Bitmap setMarkerDrawable2(String dato) {
        int background = R.drawable.marcadorazul;

/* DO SOMETHING TO THE ICON BACKGROUND HERE IF NECESSARY */
/* (e.g. change its tint color if the number is over a certain threshold) */

        Bitmap icon = drawTextToBitmap(background, String.valueOf(dato));

        return icon;
    }

    public Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(int gResId, String gText) {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, gResId);
        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();

        if (bitmapConfig == null) {
            bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
/* SET FONT COLOR (e.g. WHITE -> rgb(255,255,255)) */
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
/* SET FONT SIZE (e.g. 15) */
        paint.setTextSize((int) (12 * scale));
/* SET SHADOW WIDTH, POSITION AND COLOR (e.g. BLACK) */
        paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.BLACK);

        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
        int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
        int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2;
        canvas.drawText(gText, x, y, paint);

        return bitmap;
    }


    public void CargarLista(ArrayList<String> datos) {
        double lat = 0, lon = 0, latD = 0, lonD = 0;
        String CodigoCliente = "", NombreCliente = "", RefCliente = "", telefonos = "", Op = "";
        // = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
            String dato = datos.get(i).toString();

            try {
                CodigoCliente = String.valueOf(dato.substring(0, dato.indexOf("@")));
                NombreCliente = String.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("@") + 1, dato.indexOf("$")));
                lat = Float.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("$") + 1, dato.indexOf("%")));
                lon = Float.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("%") + 1, dato.indexOf("&")));
                RefCliente = String.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("&") + 1, dato.indexOf("*")));
                telefonos = String.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("*") + 1, dato.indexOf("#")));
                Op = String.valueOf(dato.substring(dato.indexOf("#") + 1, dato.length()));

                //datos.get(0).equals("false")
                if (Op.equals("1")) {
                    Marker marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                            .title(String.valueOf(NombreCliente))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(setMarkerDrawable(CodigoCliente)))
                            .snippet(RefCliente + " Cel: " + telefonos)
                    );

                }

                if (Op.equals("2")) {
                    Marker marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                            .title(String.valueOf(NombreCliente))
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(setMarkerDrawable2(CodigoCliente)))
                            .snippet(RefCliente + " Cel: " + telefonos)
                    );


                }


            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException excepcion) {
                lat = 0;
                lon = 0;

            }
            if ((lat != 0) && (lon != 0)) {
                latD = lat;
                lonD = lon;

            }

            //marcador.showInfoWindow();

        }


        CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latD, lonD))   //Centramos el mapa en Madrid
                .zoom(15)         //Establecemos el zoom en 19
                .bearing(45)      //Establecemos la orientación con el noreste arriba
                .build();

        CameraUpdate camUpd3 =
                CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);

        mMap.animateCamera(camUpd3);

        //mMap.se
    }


    public void ObtDatos(String codigo){
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        String url = "http://www.framac.com.bo/webservice/pListBuscarE.php";

        RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();
        //parametros.put("codigo", 131);

        parametros.put ("codigo", codigo);
        //parametros.put ("dia", 2);

        client.post(url, parametros, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if (statusCode == 200){
                    CargarLista(ObtDatosJason(new String (responseBody)));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });

    }


    public ArrayList<String> ObtDatosJason(String response){
        ArrayList<String> listado = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            String texto;
            for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                texto = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("codigo")+ '@'+
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cliente")+ '$'+
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitud")+ '%'+
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitud") + '&' +
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("referencia") + '*' +
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("telefonos") + '#' +
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("entrega");


                listado.add(texto);
            }


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return  listado;
    }

}
```